# насколько можно доверять значению в $_SESSION?

Tags: php, авторизация, сессия, безопасность, аутентификация

При авторизации пользователя в массив `$_SESSION` записывается его `id` в виде  `$_SESSION['id']` (это не идентификатор `PHPSESSID`, это `id` из БД)

Задача: разрешить действия пользователю только если он находится на своей собственной странице, например, `service.info/?id=1` (при этом его `id=1`).

Вопрос: насколько безопасна подобная проверка?

```
if ($_SESSION['id'] == $_GET['id']) {
  // some HTML-code
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, `$_SESSION['id']` находится на сервере и пользователь с другим  id не может подменить значение в массиве $_SESSION, но так ли это? (Вопрос не отменяет необходимость [полномасштабной проверки](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=protocols&page=003) при внесении изменений в БД, речь идет об отображении дополнительных элементов интерфейса).

Comment: Да, данные находятся на сервере, другой пользователь не может подменить значения (если не украдет актуальный идентификатор), проверка безопасна.

Comment: Судя по всему, сломать все же можно и это. Здесь (https://intsystem.org/security/nikogda-ne-doveryaj-svoim-polzovatelyam), обсуждая пост (https://forum.antichat.ru/threads/72298/#post-713797), пишут, что не всё так однозначно.

Comment: Сломать можно многое, однако, если вы не допускаете XSS-инъекций, это практически невозможно и очень дорого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне безопасно. Так и надо делать

```
if($page["owner_id"] == $_SESSION['id'])
//
 ...
```

Если будут крутится деньги, то можно добавить https, токены и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Принимаю ответ и благодарю @cheops как давшего такой же ответ.